# C# ManualResetEvent

Tags: c#, socket, thread

Para que serve no código abaixo o ManualResetEvent connectDone? Se eu utiliza-lo, ao executar a thread principal trava, como estou utilizando esse código dentro do Unity3D(game engine) ele trava o processo inteiro e isso não pode ocorrer.

Qual a real necessidade de utiliza-lo? Para que serve?

```
//static ManualResetEvent connectDone = new ManualResetEvent(false);
static ManualResetEvent sendDone = new ManualResetEvent(false);
static ManualResetEvent receiveDone = new ManualResetEvent(false);

public static void Connect() 
{
    string ServerIP = "127.0.0.1";
    int ServerPort  = 5902;
    try
    {
        EndPoint remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(ServerIP), ServerPort);
        Socket clientSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream,  ProtocolType.Tcp);
        clientSocket.BeginConnect(remoteEP, new AsyncCallback(ConnectCallback), clientSocket);
        //connectDone.WaitOne();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Debug.LogError(e.ToString());
    }

}

private static void ConnectCallback(IAsyncResult ar) 
{
    try 
    {
        // Retrieve the socket from the state object.
        Socket client = (Socket) ar.AsyncState;

        // Complete the connection.
        client.EndConnect(ar);

        Debug.Log("Socket connected to " + client.RemoteEndPoint.ToString());

        // Signal that the connection has been made.
        //connectDone.Set();
    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        Debug.LogError(e.ToString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No caso que apresenta o `ManualResetEvent` está a ser utilizado como flag de sinalização de forma a que o método `Connect(...)` só retorne após a ligação ter sido estabelecida.

Dado que tem o `ManualResetEvent` a bloquear o método não há benefícios em usar uma chamada assíncrona. Seria mais simples e fácil de manter mudar o código para:

```
socket.Connect(...);
```

Neste caso o método ficaria retido nesta chamada síncrona e só avançaria após a ligação ser estabelecida.

Se precisar que o código corra de forma assíncrona pode, como fez, retirar o `ManualResetEvent` ou utilizar:

```
socket.ConnectAsync(...);
```